# Call of a method as a block

Tags: ruby, refactoring

Beginner in ruby world, I would like to do something like:

```
[1,2.0,"a",2].select(&:is_a?(Integer))
```

but like this it definitely don't work...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&:method_name` is syntactic sugar for `&:method.to_proc`. Enumerators like `select` and whatnot accept a block and yield each element of the enumerator to the passed block. That is:

```
[1,2,3].select &:even?
```

is equivalent to:

```
p = :even.to_proc
[1,2,3].select {|val| p.yield(val) }
```

Since only the parameters yielded by the enumerator are yielded to the proc, you would have to include them in the source list. That is, we might expect:

```
[[1, Integer]].select &:is_a?
```

to result in:

```
select {|*args|, p.yield(*args) }
```

However, remember that `p` isn't a method bound to any particular class! It's going to try to invoke the given method on the passed argument. So, it's going to try to invoke `Array#is_a?` with no arguments, rather than splatting the arguments out and invoking `Integer#is_a?(Integer)`.

So, to accomplish this, we'll have to somehow create a proc that binds the passed arguments, and then calls the given method on the yielded receiver with the passed args. We can do this by adding a method to the Symbol class:

```
  class Symbol
    def with_args(*args)
      proc {|receiver| receiver.send(self, *args) }
    end
  end

  [1, "a"].select &:is_a?.with_args(Integer)
```

While it's perhaps not amazingly clean, it does work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you are asking for because when you use the `&` syntax you have to use a method that doesn't take parameters.

However, if you for some reason you really want to do something like that, you need to make a method that doesn't take parameters like so:

```
class Object
  def is_an_integer?
   is_a? Integer
  end
end
```

You can then do:

```
[1,2.0,"a",2].select(&:is_an_integer)
```

Comment: Actually, you can skip `self` there.